# A question about splitting a regulated power supply by resistors vs discrete components

Tags: split

Assuming the source voltage Vs is **regulated** in below diagrams, is there any advantage of using this rail-splitter topology:

[image]

instead of this simple one?:

[image]

Is there any good reason or scenario which makes the first topology superior to the second one if the power supply Vs is a regulated supply?

Comment: For both cases think what happens if you place a resistor of 1 kohm between V+ and VGND. Placing the resistor between V+ and VGND means that the supply is loaded **asymmetrically**.

Comment: You emphasize that Vs is regulated, but does that actually matter for splitting the supply? The function of the splitter is to create a virtual ground point. That can still be done when vs varies.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I plan to use one of these above to power a dual supply opamp's rails. Or to power a Wheatstone bridge. I dont think in my case there will be balance issue (?) I was wondering if the second one is sufficient or the first one is better.

Comment: *I dont think in my case there will be balance issue* If an opamp's output has a voltage other than zero and this causes a current to flow to ground you **will** have an imbalance.

Comment: But then this splitter cannot be used for powering opamps or Wheatstone excitation? I mean in what application for example it would be okay to use the first topology? Is it totally useless?

Comment: We never said **cannot**. The simple one (no transistors) can always be used **BUT** you have to accept a varying VGND (supply not being symmetric) and/or make a **HUGE** current flow through the two resistors. I could make 10A flow through the two resistors, then a 10 mA imbalance is nothing, it can be ignored. But 10A at Vs is very likely a lot of power. That's not efficient. The circuit with the transistors can supply 10 mA imbalance without needing a constant 10A flowing.

Comment: Interesting, but I dont understand why such a huge current needed for 10mA balance. What if choosing resistors HUGE like 47Meg each? Secondly how does the first topology is independent of huge current need. I would be glad if you can write these in more detail as an answer. Could it be explained here? Or too complicated?

Comment: And " circuit with the transistors can supply 10 mA imbalance" How did you quantify this imbalance? thanks

Comment: You're too much stuck on the numbers and you don't understand what is actually happening in each case. Compared to 10A, 10mA is 1000 times smaller so in most circuits I can just ignore the influence of 10mA. If you want a 0.0001% accurate balancing, you cannot ignore it. But usually 1% imbalance is OK. The transistor based circuit can handle 10 mA better (less imbalance) because one of the transistors will simply "open" and supply the current. This is all basic circuit analysis. It can be learned from books on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one can sink more current through the "ground."

Its impedance is set by the 10 ohm resistors and the transistors.  Fairly low impedance.

In the second diagram, the current is set by the resistors and the voltage rails.  4.7k is going to limit the current drastically in comparison to the first circuit.

Comment: I dont get how this transistor circuit work. But if the load is between V+ and V-, I see no imbalance in simulation. But if there is a load is between lets say V+ and VGND, then the V+ and V- changes with that load... I want to use that for this sensor:https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf which requires +-15V excitation and it has built-in amplifier. I want to power four of these sensors by using the transistor splitter(+-12V) from a 24V regulated supply. Since I dont know the inners of the sensors Im a bit confused if it would be alright to use this topology for this application.

Comment: Those sensors draw 10mA each.  Four in parallel would be 40mA.  At 24V that's a load of 600 ohms.  Or 1200 if you only consider the halves.  Your second circuit has no chance at all.  Put a 1200 ohm resistor in parallel with one of the 4.7k resistors and consider what will happen to the voltage divider.

Comment: The first would probably work.  You confuse me, though, with your comment about V+ and V- changing when you put the load between V+ and Vgnd.  The voltage from V+ to V- should stay the same (unless your powersupply is utter crap) when put a load from V+ to Vgnd.  From V+ to Vgnd might change under load, if the load is too much (resistance too low, draws too much current.) What are you using for a load in your simulation?  Probably ought to be like 600 ohms.

Comment: Sorry I meant the "voltage difference" between V+ and VGND changing changing when I put the load between V+ and Vgnd. The voltage from V+ to V- is well regulated. What I mean and confused is the "voltage difference" between V+ and VGND is not regulated. Does that matter for this application? I mean I dont know if there can be very different loads between  between "V+ and VGND" and  between "V- and VGND". Is there a way to estimate the imbalance for this application if I use the first transistor circuit?

Comment: The voltage shouldn't change much.  What are you using for a load in your simulation?

Comment: I add different R3 and R4 please see this link I uploaded the diagram: https://i.imgur.com/l01TFnH.png "voltage difference" between V+ and VGND is not regulated at 12V it varies with R3 and R4. I dont know if what Im trying to figure out makes sense because I dont know the inner circuitry of the sensors.

Comment: R3 R4 represents the load in the sensor (I dont know if it is realistic)

Comment: R3 and R4 will probably be close to equal when using the sensors.  Given the trouble you are having, it will probably be easier just to use two 12V powersupplies in series.

Comment: Thanks, one last question. I think I will go with the transistor circuit, you are right it is affected much less comparing to resistive 2nd circuit if the loads are asymmetric. But if "R3 and R4 will probably be close to equal when using the sensors." Why would that be problem for the second resistive topology if we dont expect a very unbalanced load? Wouldnt that be something like this https://imgur.com/a/L3bhR

Comment: The problem is that the purely resistive circuit can't deliver any current.  24V divided by 4.7k Ohms is only 5mA.  That can't supply one sensor, let alone 4.

Comment: But here https://imgur.com/a/L3bhR the current comes from 24V supply, and in simulation it works. Im 100% sure what you say is damn right, its just I cannot picture what you mean. If you add a small diagram circuit about what you mean I would be so glad. thanks

Comment: The current has to flow through the virtual ground.  That's what its for.  The only return path to the power supply from the virtual ground is through those two 4.7k ohm resistors.

Comment: But isn't the current circulating this way:https://i.imgur.com/r2Zek4s.png (I marked the path red) This does not pass through 4.7k

Comment: Those two triangle shaped ground symbols are connected together the current flows through the load, into the virtual ground, through the 4.7k resistor and back to the powersupply.  Except, that your load resistors are so small that almost all ofbthe current goes through other half of your load.