# Using an interface and virtual ground with a non-isolated power supply

Tags: power-supply, virtual-ground

[image]

If I use the above rail-splitter with a 24V non-isolated power supply, what can be the problem when used with any load like an opamp ect.?

How would the current loop if the power supply is not isolated through the earth and cause problem? (Please illustrate the current loop if possible.)

Comment: How is this question different to your previous one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333896/a-question-about-splitting-a-regulated-power-supply-by-resistors-vs-discrete-com?

Comment: Is that also asking how the current would loop if the power supply is not isolated? Hmm

Comment: What do **you** think will happen if the 24V ground and the virtual ground are connected to the same node? Take a  minute to think about that. Conclusion it is **essential** that the virtual ground .....  connected to the ground of the 24 V supply.

Comment: I really cannot picture it.

Comment: If Vcc and -Vcc are shorted I can see the issue. But in this case I am stuck even though it seems stupid.

Comment: Think harder then, draw the schematic and imagine what happens. Imagine you're capacitor C4, what is the difference between 1) the ground of 24 V supply is **not in any way connected** to the virtual ground on the right side 2) ground of 24 V supply is **shorted** to the virtual ground on the right side

Comment: C4 will be bypassed and C3 will see a twice voltage across. is that correct?

Comment: If the 24V ground and the virtual ground are shorted then indeed C4 will be shorted. C3 would simply be in parallel with the 24 V input. So you'd have a 24 V single supply again, same as what you started with. Conclusion: the 24 V input ground and virtual ground at the output **must not be shorted**.

Comment: I dont get this. If VGND is not connected to earth why would nonisoated supply be a problem? You say "Conclusion: the 24 V input ground and virtual ground at the output must not be shorted." Please imagine VGND is not earthed. And the supply is not isolated. Is this still an issue?

Comment: This does not mean that the 24 V supply cannot have a (mains) ground connection. That would still be OK as long as the virtual ground on the right is **not** connected to it. If you do want to connect the virtual ground to mains ground then the 24 V supply **must** be a floating one.

Comment: I see, regarding your last sentence:  "If you do want to connect the virtual ground to mains ground"In that case 24V supply must be either floating(earth not connected) or isolated right?

Comment: @Transistor I think the OP is going for the record of longest chain of questions on the same subject.

Comment: @Trevor Now really settled, promise no more trash

Comment: @user134429 :) Just pulling your leg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the true ground connection at the power supply is the **ONLY** ground connection it will not be a problem.

The real issue comes with what you do with your signal outputs. Consider the schematic below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frgzjo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A simplified version of your virtual ground circuitry is shown on the left with the power supply grounded on the negative pin. That part should work as expected.

However, when you feed the output if the first circuit to a second box, or somewhere else in the same box, and that second part also has a ground connection to the real ground you create a short between your virtual -12V and ground.

At that point, at best, the circuitry no longer functions as expected, at worse you can exceed the input voltages on the right hand circuit and burn something.

If your left hand circuitry is stand alone and does not connect to any other device, then power supply isolation should not matter. I say should, because if your power supply is not isolated and your gizmo is in a metal box that is grounded, you need to make sure the virtual ground does not touch that case anywhere.